# Laravel Nova page detail not found due to The relationship

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-nova

I am trying to test the tool I have been created. When I used relationship field in one of my resource, the page detail on this resource give me Not found.
/* My Relationship field */ **(Ticket Resource)**

```
HasMany::make(__('Replies'), 'replies',Reply::class)
```

/* Include */

```
use TicketWhmcs\TicketWhmcsPackage\Nova\Reply;
```

/* Ticket Model */

```
<?php

namespace TicketWhmcs\TicketWhmcsPackage\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TicketWhmcs\TicketWhmcsPackage\Traits\API;
use TicketWhmcs\TicketWhmcsPackage\Models\TicketReplay;

class Ticket extends Model 
{
    use HasFactory, API;

    protected $table = 'tickets';

    protected $fillable = [
        'tid',
        'user_id',
        'dept_id',
        'subject',
        'message',
        'priority',
        'status',
        'admin',
    ];

    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'dept_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the replies for the Ticket
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TicketReplay::class);
    }



}
```

/* My resource */

```
namespace TicketWhmcs\TicketWhmcsPackage\Nova;
```

My Reply Resource

```
<?php

namespace TicketWhmcs\TicketWhmcsPackage\Nova;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;

class Reply extends Resource
{
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = \TicketWhmcs\TicketWhmcsPackage\Models\TicketReplay::class;

    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'id';

    /* Sort */
    public static $sort = [
        'id' => 'desc',
    ];

    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [
        'id', 'admin',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
            Text::make(__('Message'), 'message')->hideFromIndex(),
            Text::make(__('Message'), 'message')->displayUsing(function ($value) {
                return Str::limit($value, 50);
            })->onlyOnIndex(),
            Text::make(__('Author'), 'admin')->displayUsing(function ($value) {
                if ($value) {
                    return 'Admin';
                } else {
                    return 'You';
                }
            })->hideWhenCreating(),
            Text::make('Last Update', 'updated_at')
                ->displayUsing(function ($lastActive) {
                    if ($lastActive === null) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    return $lastActive->diffForHumans();
                })->hideWhenCreating(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cards available for the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the lenses available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function lenses(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the actions available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function authorizedToUpdate(Request $request)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function authorizedToDelete(Request $request)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        if (empty($request->get('orderBy'))) {
            $query->getQuery()->orders = [];

            return $query->orderBy(key(static::$sort), reset(static::$sort));
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I register My resource in **NovaServiceProvider**

```
public function resources()
    {
        Nova::resources([
            Reply::class
        ]);
    }
```

And it's worked!